# Node Red Debug node not working in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, debugging, twitter, ibm-cloud, node-red

I would like to know if anyone has suggestions for how to fix my broken debug node.  So far I've done the following:

1) I have set up an inject node with a repeating message that sends the string: "Repeated Message," every 1 second.  I've also connected this node to a debug node.  When I deploy with this configuration (making sure that the debug deactivation sidebar is not selected), I see nothing on the debug output.

2) I've also set up one twitter input linked to my account that searches for basic keywords in actively sent tweets. I've also connected both a debug and a Twitter node which publishes the tweets with my desired key word.  It's strange because, the debug node does not send any info to the debug tab after being deployed.  However, my twitter account is constantly publishing each tweet that contains my chosen keyword.

I'd appreciate any help pointing to why the debug node is not working.

Comment: Is there anything in the console logs for the application indicating any issues?

Comment: I do see the debug information being sent to the logs when I select the debug node and change the setting to publish to the debug tab and console.  But, I don't see anything in the console log indicating an issue as to why it wouldn't publish in the debug tab.

Comment: Do you have a 'lost connection to server' message at the top of the page? If not, can you open the Chrome developer tools (assuming Chrome) and look for any errors in the console. If nothing there, open the 'Network' tab, filter for 'comms' (may need to reload page with tools open to see it) and report back the state - will be a websocket connection (that's what debug uses).
Finally, try accessing your instance using https rather than http and see how you get on.

Comment: I tried switching browsers from Google Chrome V 48.0.2564.82 m to Internet Explorer.  Works like a charm and all debug information is now sent to the debug window in my flow editor.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you have the debug node such that the sidetab is green as shown in pic below?  [image]
If it is white, it will not show the data in your debug window.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I do indeed have the debug node sidetab extended and active.  Yet, no data is sent to the debug tab.  However, I have noticed that I can see the debug information when I go to the dashboard and select logs.  The injected message is displayed and recorded, but this info never appears in debug on my flow editor

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation. In my case I has been set USERID and PASSWORD authentication in IoTF environment variables. Today I took off these authentication information of user ID and password from my environment variables. Then Debug Node is working well.

I hope this can help you.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, add your application address in the exceptions of your web browser. It worked for me, I had the same issue as you did while using Firefox